# Advanced MySQL query to get range of latest records with same id and different subids

Tags: mysql

I have a table called sensorvalue like this:

```
station_id   sensor_id   Timestamp            Value
----------------------------------------------------------
1            1           2013-09-04 12:00:00  12.2
1            2           2013-09-04 12:00:00  13.1
1            3           2013-09-04 12:00:00  13.2
1            1           2013-09-04 12:05:00  12.1
1            2           2013-09-04 12:05:00  14.1
1            3           2013-09-04 12:05:00  13.2
1            1           2013-09-04 12:10:00  12.5
1            2           2013-09-04 12:10:00  13.3
1            3           2013-09-04 12:10:00  14.1
```

I need a MySQL query that gets all the latest values of all three sensors of station with station_id 1. I wonder if this is possible with one MySQL statement.

I've managed to get the data out of the table, but not in an efficient way. Now I first SELECT all different sensors for station 1 and afterthat I call another MySQL SELECT statement foreach sensor. Some of the stations have over 10 sensors, so with this approach I need at least 11 MySQL statements to get the data out of the database.

I would like to include this in one MySQL statement. Is that possible? And how?

Comment: have you tried writing query that makes use of group by clause? something like group by sensor_id, order by Timestamp desc ?

Comment: Consider providing a sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH the desired result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: The answer is _yes_, it's possible... a GROUP_CONCAT and ORDER BY Timestamp DESC and LIMIT combination isn't even that advanced, IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the latest reading for all sensors on all stations.

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM (SELECT station_id, sensor_id, MAX(Timestamp) as max_timestamp
          FROM sensorvalue
         GROUP BY station_id, sensor_id
       ) m
  JOIN sensorvalue s
    ON s.station_id = m.station_id
   AND s.sensor_id  = m.sensor_id
   AND s.Timestamp  = m.max_timestamp
```

To limit it to a specific station.

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM (SELECT station_id, sensor_id, MAX(Timestamp) as max_timestamp
          FROM sensorvalue
         WHERE station_id = 1
         GROUP BY station_id, sensor_id
       ) m
  JOIN sensorvalue s
    ON s.station_id = m.station_id
   AND s.sensor_id  = m.sensor_id
   AND s.Timestamp  = m.max_timestamp
```

Comment: Just to let you knoww: Although this solution worked fine, I decided not to use this query anymore. The reason is performance in a big database. I have now rewritten this and use php plus serveral MySQL statements.

Comment: I have a similar setup, and I've found that with a few million rows in the database this query is slow. So I've replaced every occurrence of `millionrowtable` with `(select * from millionrowtable order by timestamp desc limit 1000)` and it goes 10-20x faster. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to write this.  The follow is probably the simplest code, using a `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select sensor_id, max(TimeStamp),
       substring_index(group_concat(Value) order by TimeStamp desc), ',', 1) as LastValue
from sensorvalue sv
where station_id = 1
group by sensor_id;
```

EDIT:

All the timestamp values look like they are the same.  If this is true, you can also do:

```
select sv.*
from sensorvalue sv
where station_id = 1 and
      timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from sensorvalue where station_id = 1);
```

Comment: Not all timestamp values are always equal. The update frequency of the sensors is not equal, so the second option will not work.

The first option is a briliant solution. A very short MySQL statement and an EXPLAIN of the query shows that it only executes one simple query. However I doubt whether this is a smart solution with many records. A ran the query in a test database with about 100 records per sensor. In the production database every sensor will write a record every 5 minutes. group_concat(Value order by TimeStamp desc) will return a very large string with all the values of all records.

Comment: Update of my comment: just found in the documentation that the result of a GROUP_CONCAT() has a maxlength (default 1024). So I don't think there will be an issue with a huge number of records. From the documentation: "The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024"